# Merging arrays within an array, preserving numeric index

Tags: php, arrays

Array_merge and array_merge_recursive are not working as desired, creating more indexes instead of pushing the arrays together and retaining the index number. See below for input/desired output:

```
Array (
    [0] => array(
        [0] => "string1",
        [1] => "string2",
        [2] => "string3"
    ),
    [1] => array(
        [0] => "string4",
        [1] => "string5",
        [2] => "string6"
    ),
    [2] => array(
        [0] => "string7",
        [1] => "string8",
        [2] => "string9"
    )
)
```

Desired Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => array("string1","string4","string7"),
    [1] => array("string2","string5","string8"),
    [2] => array("string3","string6","string9")

)
```

EDIT:

Perhaps not the best example; I want to achieve the same results but with an unequal number of keys in each nested array. See below for a better example:

```
<?php
$array = Array (
[0] => array(
    [0] => "string1",
    [1] => "string2",
    [2] => "string3"
    ),
[1] => array(
    [0] => "string4",
    [1] => "string5",
    [2] => "string6"
    ),
[2] => array(
    [0] => "string7",
    [1] => "string8",
    [2] => "string9"
    ),
[3] => array(
    [0] => "string10",
    [1] => "string11",
    [2] => "string12"
    )
);

$output=array();
    for($0=0;$j<count($array[0]);$j++){
        $output[$j] = array();
    }

for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    for($0=0;$j<count($array[0]);$j++){
        $output[$j] = array_push($output[$j],$column_values[$i][$j]);
    }
}


?>
```

But when I do this, I get the correct number of keys in my $output array, but they all contain a bool(false). Any help?

This is the desired output:

```
Array (
    [0] => array("string1","string4","string7","string10"),
    [1] => array("string2","string5","string8","string11"),
    [2] => array("string3","string6","string9","string12")
)
```

Comment: I don't think merge is the right method here anyways. You want to restructure the whole array, so iterate over the elements and create a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to make an array just for this structure of array, so you may change the code depanding on your needs ...

```
<pre>
<?php
    $array = array(array("string1","string2","string3"),array("string4","string5","string6"),array("string7","string8","string9"));
    $output=array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($array[0]);$i++){
        for($j=0;$j<count($array[0]);$j++){
            $output[$i][$j] = $array[$j][$i];
        }
    }

    print_r($output);
?>
</pre>
```

Comment: This works great for this example, where there are the same number of keys in both input arrays, but what if there are more keys in the first array than the second?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Last loop should simply `array_push($output[$j],$column_values[$i][$j]);` instead of trying to set the variable `$output[$j] = array_push(Yadda,yadda)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is for your 'second' situation:

```
<?php

    $array = array(array("string1","string2","string3"),array("string4","string5","string6"),array("string7","string8","string9"),array("string10","string11","string12"));
    $output=array();

    for($i=0;$i<count($array[0]);$i++){
        for($j=0;$j<=count($array[0]);$j++){
            $output[$i][$j] = $array[$j][$i];
        }
    }
    print_r($output);
?>
```